# Unable to checkin to git from VS Code

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I am trying to check in code from VS Code but I am not able to do it but getting the below error message. I changed LF to CRLF in VS code as well.

```
error: insufficient permission for adding an object to repository database .git/objects
fatal: could not open '.git/COMMIT_EDITMSG': Permission denied
> git config --get-all user.name
> git config --get-all user.email
```

and I am getting the below error message in the terminal when given git add

```
error: insufficient permission for adding an object to repository database .git/objects
error: <file path here has been removed while posting by me >: failed to insert into database
error: unable to index file '<file path here has been removed while posting by me >'
fatal: updating files failed
```

Comment: Check the permissions you have set for yourself on the `.git` folder.